# Calculating $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)^n $

Tags: calculus, limits

While calculating the following limit:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)^n $$

I have used the following procedure:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)^n =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\frac{1}{n}\cdot(n-3)}{\frac{1}{n}\cdot n}\right)^n =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^n = \\=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{3}{\infty}\right)^\infty = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{3}{\infty}\right)^\infty =
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1)^\infty = 1\\
\end{align}

I'm aware that the solution is $ e^{-3} $ but I'd like to know that rules I'm breaking in my process so the answer is wrong. I'm suspicious of the last two steps. I think that assuming that $ 3/\infty $ tends to 0 as $ n $ approaches $ \infty $ is fine and the result would approach 1 without the power. But in this case, the power makes the result approaches $ 0.05 $ instead.

Comment: You could intuitively think about $3/\infty\to 0$ but $x^{\infty}$ is never a thing. If $x$ approaches $1$ from the left you get "$x^\infty$"$=0$ but when $x\to 1^+$ you get infinity. Therefore it is not defined and you cannot think in that way. If you really doubt your deductions it will really help if you do this with the $\delta-\varepsilon$ formal language.

Comment: $n\to\infty(1-\frac{3}{n})^n=e^{-3}$

Comment: You write "$\infty$" as though it was a number.

Comment: $n$ appears in two places, that balance each other.  $1-3/n$ approaches 1, but the exponent keeps it away from 1.  You can't disturb the balance by sending $1-3/n$ all the way to 1.  It's like $(n-1)/n$, which does not approach $(n-1)/\infty$ or zero.

Comment: Just remember that as $\frac 00$ the form $1^\infty$ is also undertermined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this step

$$\ldots=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^n =\ldots$$

we can't "plug" $\infty$ to solve since $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form.

We can use

$$\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^n=\left[\left(1+\frac{(-3)}{n}\right)^{\frac n{(-3)}}\right]^{-3}$$

and conclude by the standard limit

$$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e $$

Comment: I think this is not what the OP asks for? OP wrote that they could evaluate the limits but asked what rules did they break

Comment: You are right, I fix that!

Comment: Thanks! It seems that knowing the limit definition of $ e $ is a requirement then.

Comment: Absolutely! You are welcome, Bye.

Answer (score 1):

One of the many ways
$$a_n=\left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)^n=\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^n\implies \log(a_n)=n\log\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)$$ Now, using Taylor
$$\log(1+\epsilon)=\epsilon -\frac{\epsilon ^2}{2}+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$
$$\log\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)=-\frac{3}{n}-\frac{9}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\log(a_n)=-3-\frac{9}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=\frac{1}{e^3}-\frac{9}{2 e^3 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ shows the limit and how it is approached.

Comment: I think this does not show what rules were broken? It's just the evaluation

Comment: This is probably the best way of doing this problem w/o using the definition of $e$.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi. I wrote *"one of the many ways"*

Answer (score 0):

As you proceed,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{3}{n})^n 
=\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{n \ln(1-\frac{3}{n})}
 =\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\frac{ \ln(1-\frac{3}{n})}{1/n}} =e^{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{3}{n^2}}{\frac{-1}{n^2} (1-\frac{3}{n})}} ( \text{by L'hospital rule}) $$

So, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{3}{n})^n = e^{-3} $$

Comment: What rule did the OP break?

Comment: @Anindya Prithvi $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^n = \\=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{3}{\infty}\right)^\infty $ ,                                   
      this is where, op did wrong.

Comment: I think this concerns OP more than the evaluation itself, so this should be in the answer?