# Use of Hôpital's rules to calculate also the sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, limits-without-lhopital

Hoping that my question is clear, I would like to understand because the L'Hôpital's rules are used in several questions on Math.SE (an answer for [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782917/calculating-lim-n-to-infty-left-fracn-3n-rightn)) to calculate the sequences,

$$(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}, \quad \text {or} \quad \{a_n\}, \quad n\in\Bbb N$$

During my university period I had been instructed that Hôpital's theorems cannot be applied.

Comment: *“the L'Hôpital's rules are used in several questions on Math.SE to calculate the sequences”* – a concrete example (with a link to the Q&A) would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR Surely. I have added a link of an answer. Best regards. +1 for the comment.

Comment: In that answer it was applied to $\frac{ \ln(1-\frac{3}{n})}{1/n}$ as a function from $[1, \infty)$ to $\Bbb R$. I.e. you have a sequence $a_n = f(n)$ where $f$ is in fact a (differentiable) function on the positive real numbers.

Comment: @MartinR I will never forget the words my mathematical analysis professor 1 said to me. You must never apply Hopital theorems to succession. I don't understand the reason now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3782926), L'Hôpital's rule is actually used to compute
$$
 \lim_{\substack{x \to \infty \\ x \in \Bbb R}} \frac{ \ln(1-\frac{3}{x})}{1/x} = \lim_{\substack{x \to \infty \\ x \in \Bbb R}} \frac{\frac{3}{x^2}}{\frac{-1}{x^2} (1-\frac{3}{x})} = -3 \, ,
$$
and that implies
$$
\lim_{\substack{n \to \infty \\ n \in \Bbb N}} \frac{ \ln(1-\frac{3}{n})}{1/n} = -3 \, .
$$
Only in that answer $n$ is used both as the (integer) index of the sequence *and* as the real-valued argument of a function.

Generally, if your sequence is $a_n = f(n)$ with a function $f: [1, \infty) \to \Bbb R$, and if you can show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = A$ (using L'Hôpital's rule or any other method), then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = A$ follows.

Comment: May I kindly ask what are the conditions under which the Hôpital's rules may or may not apply to successions? I'd like to understand the difference if that were possible. +1 for all the answers.

Comment: @Sebastiano: You don't apply it to the sequence. You apply it to $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ is the same. Using the same variable (e.g. $n$) makes it confusing and might be considered an abuse of notation.

Comment: Excuse me very much but I have not understood. Please, can you be more clear editing your answer with some examples and controexamples? thank you very much.

Comment: I have understood. Being $[0,+\infty[_{\mathbb N}\subset[0,+\infty[_{\mathbb R}$ I can apply the Hôpital's rules. It is not true? Thank you very much. It is not possible if $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The analog of L'Hospital rule for sequences is the Stolz-Cesaro theorem:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjAvLyEgYnrAhUlJTQIHayoC_YQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FStolz%25E2%2580%2593Ces%25C3%25A0ro_theorem&usg=AOvVaw1iQkM4oA1MZoySX8fqNTXe

Comment: Never I have studied Stolz–Cesàro theorem.

Comment: It was part of the standard Engineering curriculum in several European universities. I do not think it is taught anymore now.

Comment: I'm 100% sure. Never studied or been taught by my now deceased professor.